# SQL to exclude two columns

Tags: sql, where-clause

Should be simple, but cannot get query to work as I need.

Records:

| parent | item | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Main | Child1 | 1 |
| Main | Child2 | 2 |
| Main | Child2 | 1 |
| Main | Child3 | 1 |

Expected results

| parent | item | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Main | Child2 | 2 |
| Main | Child2 | 1 |
| Main | Child3 | 1 |

Tried with SQL scripts below without success:

```
SELECT item, version FROM product as i WHERE i.parent ='Main' AND 
i.item != 'Child1' AND i.version != 1


SELECT parent, item, version 
FROM product as i 
WHERE i.parent = 'Main' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT item, version FROM s_product as n WHERE n.item = 'Child1' AND n.version = 1
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1):

Well your first attempt might be on the right track, but the logic is wrong.  You want:

```sql
SELECT item, version
FROM product
WHERE parent = 'Main' AND
      NOT(item = 'Child1' AND version = 1);
```

By DeMorgan's Laws, this can be rewritten as:

```sql
SELECT item, version
FROM product
WHERE parent = 'Main' AND
      (item != 'Child1' OR version != 1);
```

Comment: Go this working, thx a lot.